# ftp_login authentication fails

Tags: php, ftp

I have something set up like this (only the names have changed):

```
$connection = ftp_connect('hostname.com') or die('Connection failure');
$login_result = ftp_login($connection, 'username', 'password');
```

This outputs the error:

```
ftp_login(): Authentication failed. in /path/to/file.php
```

Copy-pasting from my PHP into an FTP client like Cyberduck succeeds. The resource `$connection` seems to exist because otherwise it should die before the `ftp_login` line. I'm 100% sure that I have the correct username and password (as evidenced by the Cyberduck test).

The only thing that throws alarm bells in my head is that I know PHP handles strings differently when there's an `@` symbol at the front, and my password may or may not have one or more symbols in it.

---

EDIT:

Since Cyberduck is on my work machine and PHP is running on AWS, I decided to run two tests to narrow down the possibilities. I set up an SSH tunnel:

```
ssh -L 11111:foo.com:21 adam@foo.com
```

And ran Cyberduck on `adam@localhost:11111`, getting this error message in console:

```
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

Inconclusive results to me.

So I brought over the 2 lines of PHP script to my machine, and got `Authentication failed` again. So it looks like a PHP problem...

Comment: Are you using apostrophe like this? $pass = '@abc$'; if you use quotes (`"`) PHP checking this string inside to find a special characters.

Comment: @aso I'm definitely using single quotes to keep PHP from escaping. I also put in a `printf` statement at one point, and it outputted the correct password

Comment: Are you ftp-ing and using your script from the same machine?

Comment: Are you sure that you even use ftp? Cyberduck supports also sftp, which has nothing to do with ftp except the similarity of the name. So maybe you successfully use sftp with Cyberduck but try to use the same credentials for ftp in PHP?

Comment: @jeroen no, I'm using Cyberduck from my work machine and the PHP script is on AWS. I've run some more tests and will update the question accordingly.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I made sure it was an FTP connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was the password. I don't know why it's an issue, but having an ampersand (`&`) as the first character of the password was throwing things off. Changing the password to something that didn't have a leading ampersand worked.